# How to check if a string matches a value stored in a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each key has multiple lists as its values. I want to parse a certain index within all the lists to see what value they contain i.e. I want the 2nd index of the lists. I am trying to check whether or not a certain number(stored as a string) is stored there. If the number is there, I change the bit of a predefined variable from 0 to 1. I am hoping to then store this binary number as the value to the original key in another dictionary.

```
for key, value in dfDict.items():
  for sublist in value:
    channelBinary = list('0000')
    if '0' in sublist[2]:
        channelBinary[3] = '1'
    if '1' in sublist[2]:
        channelBinary[2] = '1'
    if '2' in sublist[2]:
        channelBinary[1] = '1'
    if '3' in sublist[2]:
        channelBinary[0] = '1'
```

I know this is wrong because it is going to basically check every list associated with my dictionary key and create a binary number for each list. I only want one binary number which tells me about all the values stored in the 2nd index of every list for each dictionary key. I also tried something like this

```
for key, value in dfDict.items():
  channelBinary = list('0000')
  if '0' in value[][2]:
      channelBinary[3] = '1'
  if '1' in value[][2]:
      channelBinary[2] = '1'
  if '2' in value[][2]:
      channelBinary[1] = '1'
  if '3' in value[][2]:
      channelBinary[0] = '1'
```

I know this code is wrong, but hopefully you see that I left out an index for the first square bracket of value which means I essentially want to disregard the list index and only care about the sublist index.

Edit: Sample dictionary structure. This is just the output of printing the dictionary

```
{'key1': [('data1', 'dataA', '1', 'data_a'),
          ('data2', 'dataB', '2', 'data_b'),
          ('data3', 'dataC', '0', 'data_c')],
 'key2': [('data4', 'dataD', '3', 'data_d'),
          ('data5', 'dataE', '2', 'data_e'),
          ('data6', 'dataF', '1', 'data_f'),]}
```

Comment: Can you post the sample dictionary structure?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the dictionary?

Comment: Is there any chance that for a given key, two (or more) sublists will have the same value of element #2?

Comment: @Błotosmętek No, the sublists will have unique values for element #2.

Comment: That dict is invalid, and can you post the desired output?

Comment: @NilsWernern That's the output I get when I print my dictionary

Comment: @JimKM Ok I think I now understood your question, let me know if that what you want

Answer (score 2):

Just use your first example but move `channelBinary = list('0000')` outside the inner loop:

```
for key, value in dfDict.items():
    channelBinary = list('0000')
    for sublist in value:
        for i in range(len(channelBinary)):
            if str(i) in sublist[2]:
                channelBinary[len(channelBinary) - 1 - i] = '1'
```

Comment: I think that could be the right solution, could you please help me out understand if the values of the binary string will not be overridden?

Comment: -0 is still 0, so this fails for i==0; replacing `-i` with `3-i` should work though.

Comment: Aaah... So I didn't understand well the question, well is a plus one for me then, it was a little less complicated I thought, thanks a lot

Comment: what does the i represent? I have specific numbers I want the value to be and I have a lot of them to test if they are values or not. Do I have to put in the 'for i in range...' for every value i test?

Comment: This isn't working I believe. It's giving me a binary number for every list I have in my dictionary. I should only have 2 binary numbers in the end, one for each key.

Answer (score 0):

I will add another answer because now for sure I understand what you want, if you want a binary for each key, you can do this, following your code (it could be done a lot simplier and prety, but I don't want to throw out your work here):

```
dfDict = {'key1': [('data1', 'dataA', '1', 'data_a'),
          ('data2', 'dataB', '2', 'data_b'),
          ('data3', 'dataC', '0', 'data_c'),],
       'key2': [('data4', 'dataD', '3', 'data_d'),
                ('data5', 'dataE', '2', 'data_e'),
                ('data6', 'dataF', '1', 'data_f'),]}
channelBinary = []
index = 0
for key, value in dfDict.items():
    channelBinary.append(list('0000'))
    for sublist in value:
      if '0' in sublist[2]:
          channelBinary[index][3] = '1'
      if '1' in sublist[2]:
          channelBinary[index][2] = '1'
      if '2' in sublist[2]:
          channelBinary[index][1] = '1'
      if '3' in sublist[2]:
          channelBinary[index][0] = '1'
    index += 1


print(channelBinary)
```

> [['0', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '1', '1', '0']]